# Manually Simulate "bad interpreter: Text file busy"

Tags: lock

Sometimes I get an error:

```
chmod +x a.sh
./a.sh
```

Error

```
a.sh: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: Text file busy
```

I figured out the solutions was to add a sleep between the two lines:

1. https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/9547#issuecomment-77547893
2. https://discuss.circleci.com/t/moving-then-executing-script-in-dockerfile-causes-text-file-busy-error/14583

BUT the problem is I am not able to re-create the issue which makes the text file busy. I basically want to

1. Simulate the "busy file" error 10 times
2. Add fix
3. Ensure the fix works

Comment: I think you get this message from "cp" when you try to replace a file that is at that time running. How you incorporate that in `a.sh` is up to you unless you, at the least, show us the contents of that script.

Comment: the shell script is a 3rd party file which I use as-is, https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-server/src/main/bin/gremlin-server.sh

Comment: oops I'll fix the post

Comment: From what I can find online, this issue appears to be specific to docker and possibly to particular storage containers - see for example [Docker make .sh executable and run it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052955/docker-make-sh-executable-and-run-it) ?

Comment: it works fine 100 times, just one rare case it fails. I have found a way to fix it (links in post), just need to find a way to make it fail with "busy file" error